# Can you make Craft 2 Stateless?

Tags: config, session, configuration, craft2

So we are moving to Google App Engine Flexible which means we cannot store sessions on files. So I wanted to know if anyone has been able to make Craft 2 Stateless and how was it accomplished?

Thanks.

Comment: I would use Redis as described here: [The Case of the Missing PHP Session](https://nystudio107.com/blog/the-case-of-the-missing-php-session#lets-talk-solutions) -- that's what I've used on Heroku